# Missing `.Relational()` method when update .NET Core 2.2 to 3.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, relational-database

I'm using this code in EF Core 2 and now trying to update EF Core and relational is not found

```
public static void AddDefaultValueSqlConvention(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder, string propertyName,TypepropertyType, string defaultValueSql)
{
    foreach (IMutableEntityType entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        IMutableProperty property = entityType.GetProperties()
                                              .SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name.Equals(propertyName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

        if (property != null && property.ClrType == propertyType)
            property.SetColumnType().DefaultValueSql = defaultValueSql;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

. . .

public static void AddDefaultValueSqlConvention(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder, string propertyName, Type propertyType, string defaultValueSql)
{
    foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        var  property = entityType.GetProperties().SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name.Equals(propertyName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

        if (property != null && property.ClrType == propertyType)
            property.SetDefaultValueSql(defaultValueSql);
    }
}
```

[SetDefaultValueSql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalpropertyextensions.setdefaultvaluesql?view=efcore-6.0) is an extension methoc
in the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore namespace contributed by the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll assembly.  So make sure you have the .dll referenced and the namespace imported.

Comment: @David_Browne: I use this method and get this error :
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'IMutableProperty' does not contain a definition for 'SetDefaultValueSql' and no accessible extension method 'SetDefaultValueSql' accepting a first argument of type 'IMutableProperty' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: see updated answer